# Error with PyOpenGL and glutSolidCylinder

Tags: python-2.7, pyopengl

I'm attempting to draw a solid cylinder using PyOpenGL (along with PyODE), however I am met with the following error:

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutSolidCylinder, check for bool(glutSolidCylinder) before calling
```

I have the following three imports, and have been using other glut* calls (glutSolidSphere, glutSolidCube, etc) with no issue, but this one causes me problems.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
...
glutSolidCylinder(RADIUS, LENGTH, SLICES, STACKS)
```

I'm using Python  2.7, and when I test with `print(bool(glutSolidCylinder))` I receive `False`.

I'd used Pip to install PyOpenGL as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original GLUT implementation doesn't have cylinder functions, but freeglut does ([source](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/163726-glutSolidCylinder)), (then, Python 2.7.1, PyOpenGL 3.0.1 with FreeGLUT 2.6.0 together work well on Ubuntu 12.04).

However, you can make a cylinder also with GLU functions, in Python:

```
quadratic = gluNewQuadric()
gluCylinder(quadratic, BASE, TOP, HEIGHT, SLICES, STACKS)      # to draw the lateral parts of the cylinder;
gluDisk(quadratic, INNER_RADIUS, OUTER_RADIUS, SLICES, LOOPS)  # call this two times in the appropriate environment to draw the top and bottom part of the cylinder with INNER_RADIUS=0.
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, however I was somewhat confused as the [PyOpenGL documentation clearly states](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ctypes/pydoc/OpenGL.GLUT.html#-glutSolidCylinder) there is a glutSolidCylinder method, yet it doesn't exist when you try to call it.